# Filtered Listview returns original position

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm filtering a listview that it's working properly. But when I click in an item of the filtered listview, it gives me the name of the item in the original position.

Example:
Items: A, B, C , D, E.
If I filter C, it returns only 1 item (C) but it shows A because it is position 0.

I have been looking for information but none of the similar questions helped me.

This is my code:

```
final FilteredListviewAdapter adapter = new FilteredListviewAdapter(AddAgentProfile.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arraymls);
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    addProfile.setMLSId(mlslist.get(position).getId());


    // THIS IS THE LINE THAT GIVES ME THE WRONG RESULT!!!
    textmls.setText(mlslist.get(position).getName());


    mls.setText("");
    dialog.dismiss();
}
});
list.setAdapter(adapter);

final EditText filter = (EditText) inflated.findViewById(R.id.et_filter);
filter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

And FIlteredListViewAdapter:

```
public class FilteredListviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

ArrayList<String> list;

public FilteredListviewAdapter(Context context, int layout, ArrayList<String> array) {
    super(context, layout, array);
    list = array;
}

@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return super.getItem(position);
}
```

}

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have finally found the solution.

The code of the Adapter is ok as I wrote it.

The only lines I have changed are in the OnItemClickListener, so now the code is like this:

```
final FilteredListviewAdapter adapter = new FilteredListviewAdapter(AddAgentProfile.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arraymls);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            addProfile.setMLSId(mlslist.get(arraymls.indexOf(adapter.getItem(position))).getId());
            textmls.setText(adapter.getItem(position));
            mls.setText("");
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
});
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Now I call the function adapter.getItem instead of list.get

Answer (score 0):

`getItem` should return the item inside the dataset at position:

```
@Override
public String getItem(int position) {
    return list.get(position);
}
```

Comment: I have tried that because I see it in a comment in another question, but it doesn't work. 

If I put that sentence, the list is not filtering properly. I get always the N first items of the original list (depending on what I filter).

If there is 1 item that fulfills the filter, then is show the item 0 of the original list. If there are 2 items, then the 2 first items of the orignal list are shown. And so on.